# Need to determine .change() on custom select menu

Tags: jquery, select

I'm using a custom select menu plugin https://github.com/derekpcollins/jquery-custom-select-menu , and I can't seem to get .change() to work in order to submit the form once an item is selected.

I would expect the following to work and it does not

```
$(function() {
$('select').change(function() {
    this.form.submit();
});
});
```

The plugin is rewriting the select to a div, and I'm assuming this is the issue. Would there be any other way to detect when an item has been selected?

Comment: in the pull Request there is a version with trigger change on the select element [github.com/derekpcollins/jquery-custom-select-menu/pull/22/files](https://github.com/derekpcollins/jquery-custom-select-menu/pull/22/files)

Comment: Thank you so much! Made the changes, and altered the below to '$('#community').change(function() {
      $('#mapForm').submit();
  });'

Answer (score 0):

Change the action in the function to this -

```
$(this).closest('form').submit();
```

Using `closest()` looks for the parent form of the select list while `$(this)` is the select list itself, wrapped in a jQuery object that can be acted upon by jQuery methods.